# How a fresher can get an entry level Software Engineer job in India after completing BE/BTech (Computer Science) if he/she was not placed in college?

Tags: software-industry, career-development, job-search, india

This is a common problem faced by most of the Indian BE/BTech Computer Science and Engineering students when their college is not providing any genuine placement to them and they leave the college without any job. Now what are the possible ways to get an entry level job in IT/Software industry in India **without any referral and previous internship experience**.

I know some of those like eLitmus and AMCAT they provide interview opportunities but I want to know more genuine ways to get a good entry level IT/Software job in India.

Like you have SAT test in US which gives you entry into a college in the same way I am asking about any test, competition or similar thing which can give me entry into an IT/Software company specially in India or international.

Comment: From what I know, there is no special solution or magic pill. You have to follow the same process, apply to companies, find referrals via friends / professors etc, look out for Fresher's walk-ins etc. I am not sure what exactly you are looking for other than this.

Comment: I am looking for a common platform used by majority of IT/Software companies to hire freshers only. I don't have any useful referral availability and I am trying in walk-ins but its scope is very limited.

Comment: Are you applying to permanent jobs only or have you considered contract gigs? I know that after I graduated college I was able to get experience and connections (and money) by jumping from contract to contract until I landed a permanent position.

Comment: I can go for contract job also because I don't have any responsibility right now to keep earning money, the only thing I care about is to get a job where I can work on widely used software product not a company website or management system developed by software consultancies which has very limited uses.

Comment: hackerearth. period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, stop thinking that being a fresher is a disadvantage. There are few companies who are looking for freshers only, for example Infosys, TCS etc. But as you guessed, they prefer to hire freshers mostly from colleges directly.

1. You should apply to as much companies as you can through job portals
   like [Naukri](http://www.naukri.com/), [Monster](http://www.monsterindia.com/) etc. Also, look for the company's website as well.
2. Try some independent projects. Showcase them on Github and include them on your resume or cover letter.
3. Email to recruiters directly, and explain in the cover letter why they should consider you. You can convey your ability to relocate.
4. Just spread the word among your friends / relatives and ask shamelessly for any referrals. Yes, shamelessly. With millions of applicants, it is very tough to get through normal process. That's a fact. I am sure you can find at least one person who knows some one working in an IT company. This can only get you the attention of a recruiter. First your resume, and then *you*, have to stand out.
5. I am not sure how effective this is, but there are many recruiting firms which help you get an interview. Try with them.

Like I said in my comment, there is no one stop solution, you just have to be persistent. It is not that difficult as you might think. Good luck.

Comment: Good tips I will follow 1, 2, 3, 5 but not 4 because I can't be shameless. Number 2 is really good and I will do some research on it. Please read last paragraph of my edited question and please share if you have any knowledge related to it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Get over it. When job hunting there's no shame in asking for leads or referrals from people you know.

Comment: Haha, precisely! I think such things wear out with time. I hope you get the job soon, else you will learn it the hard way

Answer (score 4):

First, if you have graduated and you have no job, **then getting a job is your job**. You should be devoting 8 hours a day to it.

This can include researching companies, polishing your interview skills, networking, filling out applications, polishing your resume  or CV, actually interviewing, and, for IT people, getting more experience by spending some time on personal projects that you can show off at an interview. Do not however spend less than 4 hours a day on the actual mechanics of applying for jobs (in other words, don't get seduced by the fun of your personal projects) and looking for new places to apply to. Expect to try several hundred places before success, so don't get discouraged becasue the first ten didn't work out. Don't limit yourself to big international names. Smaller companies often have less competition.

Spend some time practicing common coding tasks that are given in interviews like FIZZ BUZZ (search the Internet for things to practice). Read big thick books on programming in your chosen stack and general programming things like debugging techniques, design pattenrs that are not technology specific. You are prepraing to be able to answer interview questions.

You need to think what you can offer that other entry level people do not. If you don't have anything you see as special, neither will potential employers. So if you didn't do an internship, you need a good solid set of personal projects that are business oriented to point to. An interviewer is going to be more impressed with the guy who built a web site with a database backend than with the guy who just did class exercises. Consider if there is a charity that you could build something for while you look. (But if you do this, you will have to commit to finishing it in your off hours after you start to work. Don't volunteer to help out a charity and then dump them with no product.)

Personal projects should be in an area where you would like to work. If you are looking for business programming, then make sure you do a project that is heavy on database use and reporting and sales. If you want to work in embedded systems, then do an embedded systems project. If you want to work in mobile app dev, then do a mobile app. If you want to work in game programming (and you have a lot of MAth background), then you need sameple games to show. And so forth. Just make sure it is something that will be interesting to the people who will be interviewing you, not just interesting to college students. Use the technologies you want to get hired to use.

After each interview, write down the questions that you can remember that they asked and then go look up the answers. This way your answers will get better over time.

Comment: Your answer is good for interview preparation but my question is that how can I get more and more interview calls even from good company. Like you have SAT test in US which gives you entry into a college in the same way I am asking about any test, competition or similar thing which can give me entry into an IT/Software company specially in India, but if you know any international test of this type then please share.

Comment: There is no magic bullet, you have to research companies, find openings, and apply.  This is lots of work. You get more interview calls by applying at lots of places and by making yourself into a better candidate though getting any kind of experience you can. Right now you are like an interchangeable part with everyone else who graduated, so prep for those interviews, work on those personal and charity projects, get out and network and meet people who can help you and work your plan. You and you alone can make yourself someone who is more interesting to companies.

Comment: You don't need a test.  You need to send out well-written resumes,  Hundreds of them if necessary.

Comment: I have to tell you (because I am an American and we are blunt) that I work for a company where the majority of our employees are in India. If you had impressed me with this question, I might have taken you to chat and told you how to apply. Instead you want to be passive and want someone else to figure out what to do. That does not bode well for a potential professional employee in any industry. You don't appear to have anything that makes you special and no reason why I should want to hire you. Only you can fix that. We can't. It takes hard work and time. There are no magic bullets.

Comment: Presently I am using the same method i.e. searching for openings and then applying. I asked this question to make sure that I am not missing any other opportunities by applying different strategy in job search process. I am really happy to know that I have knowledge of all the subjects mentioned by you like design patterns, SQL queries, database design, report generation, debugging techniques and I developed more than 7 web applications in Java and .NET with back end database. Please tell me is it a good idea to carry my project for demonstration purpose in interview. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes it is a good idea to show those projects off when asked for sample work and to talk about them in interviews and phone screenings when you get asked about the things you've done. If there are any known bugs with those projects that you didn't get a chance to fix part of finding a job could be to go back and fix those issues to make the projects more presentable.

Comment: @HLGEM My comment came after yours but I assure you that while you posted your comment I was typing my own comment and I had no idea about your last comment. Because now if someone will read the comments then it looks like that I was trying to impress you because you told me that you can offer a job but its not the case. Anyway, from next time I will be careful while asking questions on stackexchange because I can get interview calls by asking questions on stackexchange also.